# Обновление данных в столбце ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Столкнулся с проблемой обновления данных в CH. Есть задача обновить данные в одном определенном столбце за определенный период.  Запрос

```
f"ALTER TABLE table UPDATE column = arrayJoin({list}) WHERE Date BETWEEN '{start_date}' and '{end_date}'"
```

не может обновить данные за пару дней ( ~4000 строк) - мутация жрёт слишком много памяти https://disk.yandex.ru/i/T39hbP7w1dc7CA. А обновлять данные нужно за последние 90 дней, иногда несколько раз в день.

Решить вопрос с помощью DELETE, а затем INSERT как я понял не получится в рамках одного столбца.

Есть ли вообще возможность в CH обновить данные в столбце за какой либо период?

Comment: Любопытно, что бы это значило ``UPDATE column = arrayJoin({list})`` . Сделать update column=<каждым элементом list>? Если в list 1000 элементов - сделать 1000 обновлений одной строки?

Comment: Может я что то не так понял, но... допустим , есть список list = [1, 2, 3 ] и таблица, в которой есть столбец column, в котором 3 строки со значениями 4, 5, 6 . Конструкция UPDATE column = arrayJoin({list}) заменит значения 4, 5, 6 на 1, 2, 3 . Проверял вроде, работает...

Comment: Я думал, достаточно ``UPDATE column = ({list})``. Ваша конструкция мне не понятна. Пойду думать, что она делает и возможна ли.

Comment: Такая конструкция запишет в каждую строку весь list https://disk.yandex.ru/i/HIOdQPsi8UXilw

Comment: Да, я понял. Вам придется уменьшить размер порции)